# Created localhost but cannot save the files on sublime due to my permissions

Tags: permissions, terminal, root, chmod

I'm not sure why this is happening. It hasn't happened in the past. I've created several localhosts on my machine, and I follow this process the same way everytime. This is what my www directory looks like in my terminal.

```
drwxr-xr-x.  7 me me 4.0k Feb 2 14:51 local.site.com
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root 4.0k Mar 16:18 local.othersite.com
drwxrwxr-x.  6 me me 4.0k Oct 13:22 local.other-othersite.com
```

I have tried all the regualar permission settings, like:
    sudo chmod 777 local.othersite.com 
and
    sudo chmod 755 local.othersite.com

I've done this as me and as root, why does it say that the local.othersite.com's user is root when the others say the user is me. I obviously can't create and save any files on sublime to code this othersite. Maybe it's something really obvious that I'm just not getting. So, if this seems like a dumb question, let me apologize in advance. I have read several tutorials on this particular issue, but I keep coming up short. Any help would definitely be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured this out and it was a really simple fix. What I did was just changed directory into my /var/www folder and did this command:

```
sudo chown -R me local.othersite.com
```

very easy fix, I just figured I'd post this in case anyone else has trouble with it in the future!